# How can I sort answers by votes without the accepted answer to be shown first?

Tags: support, feature-request

For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-five-seconds-in-a-batch-file-cmd?answertab=votes#tab-top) the 842 votes accepted answer is on top and above a 1447 votes answer when sorted by votes.

I would like to see the answers sorted purely by vote without the accepted answer to pop up on the top. Is this possible?

Comment: You can't. The accepted answer is always pinned to the top, unless given by the question author.